# Git add files, but not sub-folders in the current folder

Tags: gitlab

I want to add only the files in the current folder, but not the subfolders in there. So, using

```
git add .
```

I also set-up .gitignore with the subfolders to be ignored, with

```
folder1/file*
```

so that I have a path relative to the current location. Does git automatically detect and follow the .gitignore-file with git add? Can I test out if the folders are taken correctly without doing a real commit? I must not commit the 1 GB content in the subfolders.

If I want to ignore a full subfolder content, which of the following is to write better?

```
subfolder
subfolder/*
```

Comment: `.gitignore` ...

Comment: Could you please put in your comment in a whole sentence, so that I get your hint?

Comment: Ok, I got it. .gitignore will do the job, I think. I hope the test will work